# Syntax highlighting for java on chrome dev tool not working

Tags: gwt, google-chrome-devtools, syntax-highlighting, source-maps, gwt-super-dev-mode

we are using GWT SuperDevMode (which uses sourcemaps to show the original Java code) but when we open the Chrome Dev Tools (Version 54.0.2840.59 m) the code is not highlighted.

I see from [here](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDevelopers/posts/hgp67is6wZR) that Chrome Dev Tools supports highlighting in different languages, but I am not sure if it works with sourcemaps. Are we missing some settings?

Thanks,

Carlo

Comment: The announcement you've linked mentions workspaces support only, not sourcemaps.

Comment: My bad, but I see in several video like this one (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kx9RxrQZnFA) the java code with syntax highlight. So it must be possibile, I just don't know how.

Comment: So you can see the Java code (source maps enabled), but just the highlighting is missing? For me everything is working fine.

Comment: Indeed just the highlighting is missing, which makes it debugging a bit harder. Could it be because we do not have internet connection?